# Dynamic fields params inside the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form containing some dynamically added date fields using jQuery, In order to handle their params submitted I need to count the number of those fields, then inside the controller I can make a loop based on that number:

**application.js**

```
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#foo');
  var i = $('#foo div.bar').size();

  $(document).on('click', '#addField', function() {
    $('<div class="bar"><input type="text" id="start" name="start_'+ i +'"><input type="text" id="end" name="end_'+ i +'"></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });
```

Saying I added n input, then the html output will be:

```
<input type="text" id="start" name="start_1">
<input type="text" id="end" name="end_1">
.
.
.
<input type="text" id="start" name="start_n">
<input type="text" id="end" name="end_n">
```

My question is, how to access that "n" inside my controller?

I have to store all the dates range in one array then create multiple records based on each date.

Comment: Probably the easiest thin to do is send the number via a hidden input field, and increase the counter when you create a new field.

Comment: You are mixing it up IMHO. IDs need to be unique, and name can be the same. This will let you post an array i.e. `start[]`

Comment: i agree with @SrikanthVenugopalan. What are you trying to do ? Can you post details about your models ? there's probably a better way to do this (nested_attributes, anyone?).

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan, then `start[]` will only contain the value submitted in the last input, in order to get each params submitted they must be with different names, as I think.

Comment: @m_x, I'm working with dates range, the initial form have `params[start_date]` and `params[end_date]`, the user can click a button to add another range (the way shown in the upper code).

Comment: no, a param name ending with `[]` stores each input with the same name in an array. So something like `intermediate_dates[]` would do the job

Comment: see [the rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters) for more info on hash & array params

Comment: @m_x, I think I didn't get what you mean. can you please post a snippet based on my code?

Comment: oh sorry i didn't see your edit. Do your ranges overlap ?

Comment: @m_x, thank you, that article will be helpful.

Comment: @m_x, I'm planing to join them in one array and remove the duplicates.

Comment: posted an answer that should do the job, but I strongly advise using nested_attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, close to how `nested_attributes` are implemented (not the most beautiful javascript you'll see out there, but you get the spirit) :

```
$(function() {
  var $scntDiv = $('#foo');

  $('#addField').click( function(){
    var index = $scntDiv.find( '.bar' ).size();
    $(
      '<div class="bar">' +
        '<input type="text" class="start" name="ranges[' + index + '][start]">' +
        '<input type="text" class="end" name="ranges[' + index + '][end]">' +
      '</div>'
     ).appendTo( $scntDiv );
     return false;
  });
});
```

This will build a hash like this :

```
>> params[:ranges]
=> {"0" => {"start" => "a_date_string", "end" => "another_date_string"}, 
    "1" => {"start" => "a_date_string", "end" => "another_date_string"} }
```

it's then easy to process this hash, even using mass assignment :

```
class MyClass
  def ranges= ranges
    ranges.each do |*,attributes|
      # whatever logic pleases you, self.ranges.build( attributes ) for instance
    end
  end
end
```

however, if you go this way, you better use directly [nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), except if you have a very convoluted logic to perform. Nested attributes come with a lot of goodies like auto instantiation of child records, record deletion management, auto-rejection of some attributes if needed, they work well with the `fields_for` form helper, etc. It's native to rails, so why bother and reinvent the wheel ?

Comment: Thank you I'm going to elaborate my code based on your answer. I ended up with a real messy controller methode.

Comment: You're welcome. I'ts usually better to push such logic down to the model than keep it in the controller - i'ts more DRY, so more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#foo');

  $('#addField').click(function(){
    $('<div class="bar"><input type="text" id="start" name="start[]"><input type="text" id="end" name="end[]"></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    return false;
  });
});
```

This will send the params like below. for example

```
"start"=>["1", "2", "3"], "end"=>["11", "22", "33"]
```